# Characters Allowed in Google ID C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

What are the characters that are allowed in a google C2DM registration id? I saw one blog that stated it can have any unreserved url characters? Does this include a space character or a  " | "? If so, what does this not include?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a "|" in a google registration id.

[image: Only use a-z and numbers and periods]

Comment: To be more specific, I am talking about the Android C2DM registration ID